# Is “aware of” used correctly in this sentence?

Tags: phrasal-verbs, relative-clauses, coordinating-conjunctions, dangling-participles

Is there a better way to write the following sentence:

> After you called me at home – angry about a request I did not make, nor was **aware of** – I cried in front of my family.

Second, is *of* a dangling participle in the sentence?

Answer (score 2):

First, I don't believe *of* is a dangling participle because I don't believe it to be a participle at all.  [Here is a quick guide on that.](http://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/dangling-participles)

As to how to write this:

I would add I to the second clause.

> … I did not make, nor was *I* aware of …

As to why, it certainly flows better. And, I believe the second clause needs a subject here to make sense.  (I believe, but I'm not 100% certain, it is a relative clause [see here](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relative_clause))

An even better construction was suggested in comments below by @GEdgar.

> ... angry about a request I neither made nor was aware of...

This is better because using *nor* in a sentence will typically follow *neither*.  [More on this here](http://thewritepractice.com/how-to-use-either-neither-or-and-nor-correctly/)

While I don't believe it to be 100% necessary to lead with *neither*, it is certainly a better practice.  And, you cannot go wrong pairing *neither* with *nor*.  Just don't ever pair *either* with *nor*.

Comment: "... angry about a request I neither made nor was aware of ..."

Comment: Grammar Girl? Really? That quack, ugh. You ought to be downvoted just on principle. :) -- Anyway, is there a relative clause in there or not? And, without your extra "I", would it still be grammatical? . . . (Yes, I'm procrastinating.)

Comment: @F.E.  Grammar Girl was easy to understand and hence a good reference.  Plus, I did the search from my phone while waiting for a movie to begin.  As to relative clause or not, I admit my uncertainty about it, and I was hoping for a commenter to set me straight.  I'm not a grammarian, so I'm not always 100% on the proper names of constructs.  I believe it needs the I to be grammatical, but I can't back it up because I can't find the right rule to demonstrate it.

Comment: @GEdgar Yes, that is better.  I was trying to maintain the style of the original, but yours is certainly better!

Comment: @F.E. Upon further inspection, I believe I was wrong.  I believe I have edited the post correctly, now.

Comment: Er, it's a relative clause. (The other point involves a "nor" coordination.) -- For the relative clause: *a request(i) [ (that) I did not make ___(i), nor was aware of ___(i) ]*, for the gaps are the covert relativized elements that are anaphorically linked to the antecedent "request".

Comment: @F.E. OK, I've made my final revision.  I'll take my lumps if I'm wrong.  Let me know what you think.

Comment: I think the OP's use of "nor" is fine in the example, as the 2nd coordinate seems to fall within the scope of a preceding negative (though, interestingly, the OP's example isn't quite as easy to explain syntactically, due to both coordinates having their own auxiliary verb).

Comment: But I think the info about the relative clause is important for the answer, since the OP's question involves a relative clause and its relativized gaps -- one of which is located after the OP's "of". So, perhaps consider putting that info back in . . .